# Indent an Excel cell with HTML source code

Tags: html, css, excel, indentation

It is currently possible to write some HTML code for a table and Excel will understand it. It is useful for example in order to place some cell into the clipboard. For example, copy this text and paste it into Excel to see the result
(in fact, you may need to paste the text first in a Notepad, then copy again and paste in Excel. Stack Overflow is somehow messing with that.):

```
 <html><head><style type="text/css">
 .style_335544358{background-color: rgb(86,232,255); text-align: LEFT;color: rgb(255,14,7);border-top: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0); border-right: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);} 
</style></head><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td class="style_335544358"  style="mso-number-format:'#,##0.#';">
1600,0</td></table>
</html>
```

However, I have not found a way to customize Excel indentation with HTML. Excel has its own syntax for indentation (1, 2, 3) instead of the HTML/CSS way (20px etc.).

Has anyone found a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mso-char-indent`.

Like so...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .style_335544358{background-color:rgb(86,232,255); text-align:left; color:rgb(255,14,7); border-top:5px solid rgb(0,0,0); border-right:1px solid rgb(0,0,0);} 
    </style>
  </head>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="style_335544358" style="mso-number-format:'#,##0.#'; mso-char-indent:2;">
        1600,0
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

The following resource will be helpful:  https://gist.github.com/webtobesocial/ac9d052595b406d5a5c1#mso-char-indent-size

Note: as you mentioned, this will need to be copied to Notepad first as Stack adds its own CSS to display the code.

Answer (score 0):

To complete Excel Hero solution,

I just found that placing "margin-left" or "padding-left" into the css class will also work..

I wonder why I haven't found that earlier :

```
    <html><head><style type="text/css">
     .style_335544358{background-color: rgb(86,232,255); text-align: LEFT;color: rgb(255,14,7);border-top: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0); border-right: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0); 
padding-left : 2em;} 
    </style></head><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td class="style_335544358"  style="mso-number-format:'#,##0.#';">
    1600,0</td></table>
    </html>
```